# how to call HTML at Android?

Tags: android, html, android-layout

> I created new **Android** App as it display static information , i had created **html5** and i call **html5** files to my **webview** all thing worked well but i have page have **checkbox** with values **on** and **off** , as on to play mp3 and this will related with specific days and times . the question is how i can check if this **checkbox** value **on** to play this **mp3** ? .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ramadan);

    //Call HTML Files
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");


}

public void audioPlayer() {
        //set up MediaPlayer    
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("Azan.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
 <div class="switch demo3">
        <input type="checkbox" >
        <label><i></i></label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement Java script  interface to communication between JavaScript and your application is possible through `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`.

Refer: [Binding JavaScript code to Android code](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

For example, you can include the following class in your Android application:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then in your activity

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Now in html

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i did your steps but how can i play the mp3 " audioPlayer() "

Comment: For playing audio refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/ it uses MediaPlayer